# Is it possible to simulate a Google Cloud Task locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

I'm working on a Cloud Run docker application that handles a few long-running data integration processes.

I'm struggling to come up with a way to locally run/test my submissions to Cloud Tasks before actually deploying the container to Cloud Run.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. There is old emulators, but nothing really up to date and maintained by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A local emulator for Cloud Tasks is not available [yet](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/migrating#features_in_task_queues_not_yet_available_via), in some cases you can substitute Cloud Tasks with [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub).
Also, consider to use non Google solutions such as [Cloud-Tasks-In-Process-Emulator](https://github.com/doitintl/Cloud-Tasks-In-Process-Emulator), [gcloud-tasks-emulator 0.5.1](https://pypi.org/project/gcloud-tasks-emulator/) or [Cloud tasks emulator](https://github.com/aertje/cloud-tasks-emulator).

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand you want to test the cloud task locally! Yes it is possible by using ngrok. By using ngrok you can access your local application on public and for cloud task you need the public url for handling task.

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/develop-your-cloud-tasks-pipeline-locally-with-ngrok-5bee3693600f